# Spring Boot JPA Save failing for Embedded Primary Key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have struggled to make the save through JPA work. I've used a custom naming strategy for which I added this configuration in my application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none
```

This is my entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Tour_Rating")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class TourRating {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TourRatingPk ratingPk;

    @Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
    private int score;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;
}
```

This is the embedded primary key:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class TourRatingPk implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Tour tour;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int customerId;
}
```

This is the entity in the composite key class which is meant to join on the tourId variable:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Tour")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Tour {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tourId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer tourId;
....
}
```

The whole thing falls apart within the controller when the save method is called, controller below:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/tours/{tourId}/ratings")
public class TourRatingController {

    private final TourRatingRepository ratingRepository;
    private final TourService tourService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(CREATED)
    public void createTourRating(@PathVariable(value = "tourId") int tourId,
                                 @RequestBody @Validated RatingApi ratingApi) {

        Tour tour = verifyTour(tourId);
        TourRatingPk ratingPk = TourRatingPk.builder()
                                            .tour(tour)
                                            .customerId(ratingApi.getCustomerId())
                                            .build();

        TourRating tourRating = TourRating.builder()
                                          .ratingPk(ratingPk)
                                          .score(ratingApi.getScore())
                                          .comment(ratingApi.getComment())
                                          .build();
        ratingRepository.save(tourRating);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
    public String respondWith400(NoSuchElementException elementException) {
        return elementException.getMessage();
    }

    private Tour verifyTour(int tourId) throws NoSuchElementException {
        return toBusiness(tourService.retrieveTour(tourId), null);
    }
}
```

This is the repository for the TourRating:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface TourRatingRepository extends JpaRepository<TourRating, TourRatingPk> {

    List<TourRating> findByRatingPkTourTourId(int tourId);

    Optional<TourRating> findByRatingPkTourTourIdAndRatingPkCustomerId(int tourId, int customerId);
}
```

When it hits the call to "save", it throws this message:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'tourrating0_.tour_tourId' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
```

I've read through quite a number of other StackOverflow topics which mostly deal with the find/retrieve side, but haven't found anything to do with how to deal with saving an entity which has an embedded primary key.

P.S: this is my request body JSON below:

```
{
    "score" : 5,
    "comment" : "It was great!",
    "customerId" : 123
}
```

Flyway script for rating:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tour_Rating(
    tourId INT,
    customerId INT,
    score INT NOT NULL,
    comment VARCHAR(2000),
    FOREIGN KEY (tourId) REFERENCES Tour(tourId),
    PRIMARY KEY(tourId, customerId),
    UNIQUE KEY unique_rating (tourId, customerId)
);
```

Comment: How do you create the database?

Comment: Using Flyway migration script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an interesting issue which I had tried a few things only to discover, all I needed was the magic line in my embedded Primary key class below:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Embeddable
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class TourRatingPk implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    **@JoinColumn(name = "tourId", referencedColumnName = "tourId")**
    private Tour tour;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int customerId;
}
```

This helped hibernate know where to find the column to reference! Also without the @JoinColumn annotation line I added in the class above, I updated this config in application.yml:

```
hbm2ddl:
  auto: none
```

to

```
hbm2ddl:
  auto: update
```

this made hibernate create a completely new column with the column name it expected to find in **Tour_Rating** table called ('*tour_tourId*') and, complained that I need to supply a default value for the '*tourId*' column within **Tour_Rating** which was the column I expected it to populate anyway.

 So, watch out for this guys.

Mehn, programming is a beauty honestly. lol